# Differentiating under the integral sign (Dixit-Stiglitz)

Tags: calculus, integration

I have some issues understanding the solution to this Lagrangian:

$$
\mathcal{L}=\left[\int_{0}^{1} C_{t}(i)^{1-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}} d i\right]^{\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon-1}}-\lambda\left(\int_{0}^{1} P_{t}(i) C_{t}(i) d i-Z_{t}\right)
$$

The textbook says that the first-order condition should be

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon-1} \left[\int_0^1 C_t(i)^{\frac{\varepsilon-1}{\varepsilon} }di\right]^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon-1}}\frac{\varepsilon-1}{\varepsilon}C_t(i)^{\frac{-1}{\varepsilon} } -\lambda P_t(i)=0 \\
C_t^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon} } C_t(i)^{\frac{-1}{\varepsilon}}=\lambda P_t(i)
\end{align*}
$$
with $C_t = \left(\int_0^1 C_t(i)^{\frac{\varepsilon-1}{\varepsilon} }di\right)^{\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon-1}}$. I'm not sure I understand this solution, since to me, this is a case where we should apply the Leibniz rule (in the case where the bounds are fixed):
$$
F(x)=\int_c^d f(x,t)dt \Rightarrow F'(x)=\int_c^d \frac{\partial f(x,t}{\partial x}dt
$$
since $C_t(i)$ and $P_t(i)$ are functions of both $i$ and $x$. This gives us instead:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon-1} \left[\int_0^1 C_t(i)^{\frac{\varepsilon-1}{\varepsilon} }di\right]^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon-1}}\int_0^1\frac{\varepsilon-1}{\varepsilon}C_t(i)^{\frac{-1}{\varepsilon} }di -\lambda\int_0^1 P_t(i)di=0  \\
 C_t^{1/\varepsilon}\int_0^1C_t(i)^{\frac{-1}{\varepsilon} }di -\lambda\int_0^1 P_t(i)di=0 
\end{align*}
$$

Could you explain why this solution is wrong? I think my principal difficulty is that we are integrating with respect to $i$ and not $C_t(i)$.

PS: this is an application of the Dixit-Stiglitz model, and the example comes from Gali, chapter 3. Similar questions have been posted before but the answer were not clear to me.